# Structure to ByteArray Extension

Tags: c#, memory-management, generics, networking, serialization

I have a need to turn various structures into byte arrays to be sent over serial port to another machine. I created generic extensions to turn any structure into a byte array and from a byte array back into a given structure.

I've not used the `Marshal` class often, and I'm uncomfortable manipulating memory on this level.

- Do I need to explicitly free any memory?
- Is this an efficient implementation? I'll be calling this *a lot*, it's important that it's efficient in both terms of memory and speed.

---

```
public static class StructureExtensions
{
    public static byte[] ToByteArray<T>(this T structure) where T : struct
    {
        var bufferSize = Marshal.SizeOf(structure);
        var byteArray = new byte[bufferSize];

        IntPtr handle = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bufferSize);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(structure, handle, true);
        Marshal.Copy(handle, byteArray, 0, bufferSize);

        return byteArray;
    }

    public static T ToStructure<T>(this byte[] byteArray) where T : struct
    {
        var packet = new T();
        var bufferSize = Marshal.SizeOf(packet);
        IntPtr handle = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bufferSize);
        Marshal.Copy(byteArray, 0, handle, bufferSize);

        return Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(handle);
    }
}
```

---

> Example Call:
>
> ```
> var point = new Point(10,5);
> byte[] serialized = point.ToByteArray(); 
>
> Point deserialized = serialized.ToStructure<Point>();
> ```

Comment: my reading of ptrtostructure is that it will work with any type, class or struct. So you dont need the `where T : struct clause` - unless you want to impose it for some other reason. Maybe I am reading it wrong

Comment: @pm100 that's good to know. I was reading a bit, and it seems you're correct. Only, if it's a reference type, you have to call the DestroyStructure method. Since I'm only using this to serialize some struct's for transport, I think I'll leave it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Structs with strings cause an AccessViolationException on x64 builds**

The code below gives me an `AccessViolationException` on `Marshal.StructureToPtr` in `StructureExtensions.ToByteArray` on an x64 build (both Release and Debug).

```
[Serializable]
struct MyStruct
{
    public int w, x,y,z;
    public string a,b,c;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    MyStruct testingStruct = new MyStruct();

    testingStruct.w = 86;
    testingStruct.x = 75;
    testingStruct.y = 30;
    testingStruct.z = 9;

    testingStruct.a = "";
    testingStruct.b = "This causes an AccessViolationException on an x64 build.";
    testingStruct.c = "Some other string.";

    byte[] structBytes;

    structBytes = testingStruct.ToByteArray();

    Console.WriteLine("Dear Compiler: Please don't optmize out " + structBytes[0].ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

I'm really curious as to why this is happening.

---

**If w,x,y,z in MyStruct are changed to bytes, it causes a hard crash to desktop instead.**

It seems to happen on both x86 and x64 builds.

- If I change w,x,y, and z to `byte`, it causes a hard crash instead of an `AccessViolationException`.
- The crash with bytes in the struct happens in `Marshal.StructureToPtr().`

---

```
[Serializable]
struct MyStruct
{
    public byte w, x,y,z;
    public string a,b,c;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        MyStruct testingStruct = new MyStruct();

        testingStruct.w = 86;
        testingStruct.x = 75;
        testingStruct.y = 30;
        testingStruct.z = 9;

        testingStruct.a = "testing";
        testingStruct.b = "";
        testingStruct.c = "Some other string.";

        byte[] structBytes;

        structBytes = testingStruct.ToByteArray();

        Console.WriteLine("Dear Compiler: Please don't optmize out " + structBytes[0].ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: It crashes before you call tobytearray?

Comment: It crashes in `ToByteArray`, in `Marshal.StructureToPtr(structure, handle, true);`

Comment: Gotcha, was a bit confused by your string 'we never get to this'

Comment: It's crashing because the struct you're using has string members. Strings are reference types. Duly noted. Thank you.

Comment: @jrh I think you have to pass false for the first call if you're using reference types like strings, then true for subsequent calls.  You could see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @RubberDuck That's a good point, Reference types like strings can grow in size, but I guess I'm confused as to why the Serializer in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10502856/4975230 is able to encode the struct without a crash. Does Marshal.SizeOf not consider the length of a string, and just add in the size of the reference instead?

Comment: It's also possibly the methodology I used to size the memory... I think because it's not possible to know up front how big the struct is when you've got a reference to a string that could be any size?? Not sure.

Comment: @forsvarir it prevents the crash but there's a bigger problem, the byte array doesn't contain the string **values**, it just contains the strings' **references**, so if the string from the original struct is changed (or worse, GC'd), the strings in the byte array will change, too.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20003830/4975230 , http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97711/sizeof-vs-Marshal-SizeOf . It looks like the Marshal functions are calculating the size of a string reference, and copying that in, not the actual string value.

Comment: From the code project link. "The struct does not contain a reference type as its member. Since the size of a reference type cannot be computed (see Reference Types below), the size of the struct cannot be computed too."

Comment: Aha! I wonder if [MarshalAs(BStr)] would fix it? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3278956/3198973

Comment: @RubberDuck That does seem to work.

Comment: Good idea, remember to check your buffer size; if there's a way to throw exceptions somehow if the string is beyond that size when you serialize, it would probably be worth doing IMO

Answer (score 9):

I haven't used it, however all of the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zhzfk83(v=vs.100).aspx) seems to suggest that you need explicitly free the memory allocated through:

```
IntPtr handle = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bufferSize);
```

With a paired call to:

```
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(handle);
```

You don't seem to need the handle after you've performed the marshalling, so it could be as simple as updating the function to:

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray<T>(this T structure) where T : struct
{
    var bufferSize = Marshal.SizeOf(structure);
    var byteArray = new byte[bufferSize];

    IntPtr handle = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bufferSize);
    try
    {
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(structure, handle, true);
        Marshal.Copy(handle, byteArray, 0, bufferSize);

    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(handle);
    }
    return byteArray;
}
```

Depending on the overhead of The AllocHGlobal / FreeHGlobal and if you're going to be marshalling the same structures over and over again you might be better off going with something like:

```
public sealed class Marshaller<T> : IDisposable where T : struct 
{
    readonly IntPtr _handle;
    readonly int _bufferSize;

    public Marshaller()
    {
        _bufferSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
        _handle = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(_bufferSize);
    }

    public byte[] ToByteArray(T structure)
    {
        var byteArray = new byte[_bufferSize];

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(structure, _handle, true);
        Marshal.Copy(_handle, byteArray, 0, _bufferSize);

        return byteArray;
    }

    public T ToStructure(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        var packet = new T();

        Marshal.Copy(byteArray, 0, _handle, _bufferSize);

        return Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(_handle);
    }


    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool disposedValue = false;

    ~Marshaller() {
       Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(_handle);

            disposedValue = true;
        }

        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion

}
```

Comment: This is a nice candidate for a helper disposable to be used like `using(var handle = new AllocHGlobal(bufferSize)) { ... }`

Comment: @t3chb0t  Funny, I was thinking disposable, but without immediate cleanup so that you could avoid the alloc/free cycle, but it really depends on the use case.

Comment: The Marshaller class isn't a terrible idea.

Comment: For the `Marshaller <T>` class both the `_handle` and `_bufferSize` could/should be `readonly`. You aren't using the `disposing` parameter of the `Dispose ()` method.

Comment: @Heslacher Agree on both counts, I have to confess I let VS template out the Dispose code and wasn't quite zealous enough in cleaning up after it.

Comment: http://dave-black.blogspot.ro/2011/03/how-do-you-properly-implement.html

Comment: I'm using the same way but this method actually copied twice (`Marshal.StructureToPtr` and `Marshal.Copy`) which is very painful to look at. Is there any better way to do this without making everything unsafe?

Answer (score 4):

You could avoid Marshal and use Serialization instead. The solution below is an example of that and it handles string, all primitive types and serializable types:

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray<T>(this T structure) where T : struct
{
  using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(stream, structure);

    stream.Flush();
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return stream.ToArray();
  }
}

public static T ToStruct<T>(this byte[] buffer) where T : struct
{
  using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
  {
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    var data = bf.Deserialize(stream);
    return (T)data;
  }
}
```

Comment: I considered this approach, but there's a significant size overhead with using the standard serialization (153 bytes compared to 8) for a Point class with 2 integers, which if it's going over a serial port *may* be a consideration.

Comment: @forsvarir it definitely *is* a consideration. Both speed and size are big concerns for me. My total packet length maxes at 20 bytes. Unfortunately this isn't viable for me, but gets a +1 because it may be useful to others.